# Different border position in chrome 29 and firefox 23 (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Html:

```
<div class="st1">
  <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
<div class="st2">
</div>
```

And css:

```
.st1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.st1 {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.st2 {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-top: 2px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uk4Ug/embedded/result/

Rendering in firefox:
[image: firefox.png]

Chrome: [image: chrome.png]

I want the same rendering in chrome as in firefox. How to fix it?

Comment: Which rendering do you want  in the end?

Comment: rendering as in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in my copies of Firefox (Stable/Nightly on OSX/Windows) your fiddle renders like what you have for "Chrome".

You could make the `a` an `inline-block` and balance the border out by a negative margin of the same size:

```
.st1 a {
     display: inline-block;
     /* ... */
}
.st1 a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    /* ... */
}
```

[Complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk4Ug/2/) based on yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a height on the div st1 so in this case:

`.st1 { height:22px;}`

That seems to do the trick.

**Note**: if you increase the font size you'll have to increase the div size.